# How to interact with prestashop data using ajax?

Tags: ajax, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a prestashop store, I wish to add some interactivity in the shop but for that purpose I need to fetch some data about the products from the database. I tried to search the prestashop docs but didn't find anything useful.

How can I interact with prestashop's products data using ajax?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a php file where you want (root folder is ok) and and start the "enviroment" like this

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../config/config.inc.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../init.php');

echo("<br />a log string " . date("H:i:s d/m/Y"));

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_STRICT);

// here you have all prestashop class
$myCategory = new Category($id)
```

after that you reach your's php in your ajax call

Answer (score 0):

1- Go to : https://validator.prestashop.com/auth/login

2- create a generic module (more fast)

3- create folder controllers/front/ajaxmain.php (example)

add:

```
    <?php

        class YOURMODULENAMEAjaxmainModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
        {


            public function __construct()
            {
                parent::__construct();

                $this->context = Context::getContext();
            }

            public function initContent()
            {
                parent::initContent();

                if (Tools::isSubmit('anysubmitname'))
                {
                        $this->getproduct();
                }

               //or Tools::getvalue("anyvalue")....

            }
     private function getproduct(){

// do your magic

            die(json_encode(array(
                "response"=> "response"
            ) ));
        }
```

Then, call it -> index.php?fc=module&module=test&controller=ajaxmain

I think that this is more clean, then you can get more things with this